# why Hibernate Session behavor like this

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, junit, transactions

I have a working **JUnit** test code testing my hibernate database access code. For **each** database access **method**, I **open** a Session and **close** it at the end inside a finally block. Everything works fine.

Now I want to open a session to **do multiple access** and let the user/caller/business module open and close the Session.

So my JUnit test code is changed as the following with a Session parameter. And inside the **each** database access method, there is a **beginTransaction** and **commit**/**rollback**.

```
//session opened before here
System.out.println("step1, load back userAccount, expect success");
UserAccount user = DataMgmtMgrTest.dataMgr.findUserAccountByTblId(user2Id, errorInfo, session);
Assert.assertNotNull(user);
Assert.assertEquals(user.getUsername(), userName2);
Assert.assertEquals(errorInfo.getCode(), ErrorCode.No_ERROR);

System.out.println("step2, update userAccount, expect fail");
user.setUsername(userName3);
boolean rslt = DataMgmtMgrTest.dataMgr.updateUserAccount(user, errorInfo, session);
Assert.assertFalse(rslt);
Assert.assertNotEquals(errorInfo.getCode(), ErrorCode.No_ERROR);

System.out.println("step3, update userAccount, expect success");
user.setUsername(userName1);
rslt = DataMgmtMgrTest.dataMgr.updateUserAccount(user, errorInfo, session);
Assert.assertTrue(rslt);
Assert.assertEquals(errorInfo.getCode(), ErrorCode.No_ERROR);

System.out.println("step4, load back check, expect true");
UserAccount newUser = new UserAccount();
newUser.setUserAccountTblId(user2Id);
rslt = HibernateDBUtil.refreshFromDB(newUser, session, true, false, errorInfo);
Assert.assertTrue(rslt);
Assert.assertEquals(errorInfo.getCode(), ErrorCode.No_ERROR);
Assert.assertEquals(newUser.getUsername(),userName1);

//session closed after here
```

My problems are the following:

In step 2, I try to update an existing row with the same alternate key (must be unique), it failed as expected and Hibernate done rollback and the database is also good.

After that in step 4, **user.setUsername(userName1);** should change the **user**'s userName to another value, userName1, the update should be done successfully. But the result is wrong. The error message tells me the **user** still has the value of step 2.

I can modify the **persistent object**, **user**, in step 2 but why cannot in step 3?

If I close the session before step 3 and reopen a session next line, then it will work.

Similar in step 4, I create an empty UserAccount, **newUser** and try to refresh the database values into it. But its **userName** is null. If I close session before these Assert.assertXXX() call,  then it will work.

Does this mean I have to open/close session for each database accession?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hibernate Session should be [discarded once you get an exception](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html):

> If the Session throws an exception, the transaction must be rolled
>   back and the session discarded. The internal state of the Session
>   might not be consistent with the database after the exception occurs.

In your test you need to use a new Session, once the previous one generated an exception. This emulates the real-life behaviour, where an exception disrupts the current business logic and notifies the user that something went wrong. Then, the user uses a new request with a new Hibernate Session anyway.

Comment: How about the second case? I reopened a new session after the exception in step 3 and instantiated a new empty UserAccount instance, newUser, with only its ID in step 4. I call session.refresh() to get values from database, I committed the transaction and called the session.flush(). But the newUser still empty until I physically close the session. Is that a normal behavior?  Should I go back to one session one database access approach?

Comment: If there's a new entity, you have to call persist. For detached ones you can call merge. Refresh is useful for detached or managed entities, to discard any dirty change and reload the latest DB snapshot.